# disable TinyMCE text editor via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, tinymce

I ahave multiple Tiny MCE editors which I am trying to disable editing on. I have tried multiple variations of:

```
if(@Model.hasRegular.ToString().ToLower()) 
        {
          tinymce.get('#rte').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        }
        if(@Model.hasSmall.ToString().ToLower())
        {
          tinymce.get('#rteSmall').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        }
        if(@Model.isOneSize.ToString().ToLower())
        {
          tinymce.get('#rteOneSize').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
        }
```

with my editors all defined similarly like:

```
tinymce.init({
          selector: '#rte',
          toolbar: 'bold italic underline',
          height: '200px',
          width: '420px',
          elementpath: false,
          menubar: false,
          content_style: "div {border: 50px solid red;}",

          setup: function (ed) {
            ed.on('init', function () {
              this.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = '16px';
              this.getDoc().body.style.fontFamily = 'Helvetica';
              //disables editing for non admins
              if ($('#nonAdmin').length) {
                this.setMode('readonly');
              }

            });
          }

        });
```

currently with what I am trying, I am getting a console error: `Cannot read property 'getBody' of null`

Comment: Check the console. if any errors are there. .

Comment: Try this in case of having multiple . .   tinyMCE.get('rte').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);

Comment: Also From version 4.3.x on you can use code below for readonly mode..
its like  tinymce.activeEditor.setMode('readonly');

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a typo in your disable code:

```
tinymce.get('#rte').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

This line must be:

```
tinyMCE.get('rte').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

So remove the # symbol.

Because you already used setMode you can do:

```
tinyMCE.get('rte').setMode('readonly');
```

or

```
tinyMCE.get('rte').setMode('code');
```

Snippet (fiddle: [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/8kwnut6o/1/)):

```js
$(function () {
  $('#nonAdmin').on('change', function(e) {
    tinyMCE.get('rte').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', !this.checked);
  });


  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#rte',
    toolbar: 'bold italic underline',
    height: '200px',
    width: '420px',
    elementpath: false,
    menubar: false,
    content_style: "div {border: 50px solid red;}",

    setup: function (ed) {
      ed.on('init', function () {
        this.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = '16px';
        this.getDoc().body.style.fontFamily = 'Helvetica';
        //disables editing for non admins
        if ($('#nonAdmin').prop('checked')) {
          this.setMode('readonly');
        }

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.4.1/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.4.1/jquery.tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<h1>TinyMCE Quick Start Guide</h1>
<form method="post">
    Disable: <input type="checkbox" id="nonAdmin">
    <textarea id="rte">Hello, World!</textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to tinymce.get() is incorrect.

The API for get (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/root_tinymce/#get) states:

Returns a editor instance by id.: get(id:String):tinymce.Editor

Parameters:
id (String) - Editor instance id or index to return.

This is not a jQuery API call so your call:

```
tinymce.get('#rteSmall')
```

...should likely be...

```
tinymce.get('rteSmall')
```

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE(latest version) text editor disable with some style on document ready.

```
    $(function () {
        tinymce.init({
                            selector: '#textEditor',
                            plugins: "advlist lists table paste textcolor colorpicker tabfocus link preview",
                            toolbar: "table fontsizeselect bold italic underline forecolor backcolor bullist numlist link preview code", imagetools_toolbar: "rotateleft rotateright | flipv fliph | editimage",
                            menubar: false,
                            toolbar_items_size: 'large',
                            min_height: 500,
                            max_height: 800,
                            convert_newlines_to_brs: false,
                            statusbar: false,
                            relative_urls: false,
                            remove_script_host: false,
                            language: 'en',
        
                        });
                        
                //controls disable inside sections
                tinyMCE.get('textEditor').setMode('readonly');  // disable
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".tox .tox-edit-area__iframe, .tox- 
                    toolbar__primary").css("background", "#eee");
                    $(".tox-tinymce").css("border", "1px solid #eee");

                }, 1000);
        });



               //if you want to enable it again, using your own button
                  $(".editFormControls").on('click', function () {
                  $(".sections form").find(".updateControl").show();
               });
```