# disable autofocus on tinymce mode change

Tags: tinymce, typescript-typings, tinymce-4

Is there a way to prevent tinymce from auto-focusing on mode change?

What I was trying to achieve is that, enable/disable the editor based on the status of parent field.

```
let mode = isDisabled ? 'readonly' : 'design';
this.editor.setMode(mode);
```

Whenever i call the code above, the editor will be auto-focused. My expectation is to remain the focus on parent field even if the status of the parent field has changed. The version of TinyMCE i use is 4.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to prevent my editor from gaining focus by using the following instead of setMode():

```
tinymce.get(id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable',false); // readonly
tinymce.get(id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable',true); // design
```

ref: [disable TinyMCE text editor via Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38878722/338801)